# Code completion for members of a class using Pydev in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, autocomplete, pydev

I'm using Eclipse Helios Service Release 1 with Pydev 2.3.0.

I have code completion working for most cases, but it doesn't work for members of a class, e.g.:

```
Class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var

    def foo(self, new_var):
        self.v <------ I'd like to get an autocompletion here please!
```

Can this be done?

Comment: In order for PyDev to know that your instance will eventually have a `var` attribute, it would need to instantiate your class. Kinda hard to do given you haven't finished writing it yet. Also, you probably don't want PyDev instantiating things.

Comment: How about autocompleting for self.foo()? Isn't it the same as its ability to autocomplete any other function (that's not inside of a class)?

Comment: I just checked the use case you posted and it did find 'var' in the autocomplete (note: your use-case has a syntax error on 'Class', which should be all lowercase) -- isn't it finding 'var' -- or you'd like the members of 'var'?

Answer (score 0):

The code completion does work. You have a syntax error Change the"Class" to "class"